# Extract difference between every 2 consecutive elements

Tags: r, diff

I have a list of numeric values, and I need to calculate a new list which will be consists of the difference of every 2 consecutive elements from the original list.
I have this code:

```
wss <- (nrow(dat)-1)*sum(apply(dat,2,var))
  for (i in 2:15) wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(dat,
                                       centers=i)$withinss)
  plot(1:15, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters",
       ylab="Within groups sum of squares")

  # choose optimal k where sos derivative is large for the first time
diff <- lapply(wss, diff)
```

so my original list is wss

```
> dput(wss)
c(4155212952468.46, 4021505707879.36, 4017356406677.14, 4015231535838.63, 
4013350949497.91, 17067610483.738, 17023281391.9182, 4013258218594.64, 
14454798910.9291, 16989216167.6064, 14860266330.575, 14480295584.8302, 
14506662229.3596, 14289181733.1553, 14283121461.9347)
```

and in the result list I would expect that first element would be 
4155212952468.46 - 4021505707879.36
second element would be
4021505707879.36 - 4017356406677.14
and so on and so forth
Any help appreciated

Comment: Please use correct terminology. What you have there is a vector and not a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use

```
diff(wss)
```

which returns a vector of the differences.

To illustrate what you did wrong. lapply should be used on a list and evaluates a function for each element in the list. This is not applicable here because: i) you don't have a list, ii) you need the differences between 2 consecutive elements and in the method you used , even if it were a list, you only supply one to the function diff

Comment: No, it returns a vector and not an array.